# Passing a file as a parameter

Tags: bash

Fellows, I have a .sh that creates a file.log, in this file I have many git logs searched from a range of dates that the user passed before (just to explain what its have).
Now I need to use this file.log that I have from a this external program and use with this code:

```
find ./* -type f -exec grep -l 'a1009206_vcr' {} \; > file.log
```

my question is how can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This code is overwriting the `file.log` file. How do you want to use it?

Comment: `grep` already has `-r`, just `grep -l 'a1009206_vcr' -r .`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect what you're looking for is `xargs 'somecommand' < file.log`. This will use the filenames in `file.log` as the arguments to `somecommand`

Comment: @KamilCuk This construction (find -type f -exec grep) is useful with POSIX tools in order to not grep files that are referenced by symbolic links, and to not get errors with dangling symlinks.

Comment: @xhienne BSD and GNU grep both have flags for dealing with symlinks, so `find -type f` isn't strictly necessary for that basic use case. There are always exceptions, though.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs That's exactly why I mentioned POSIX, and not GNU or BSD

Answer (score 0):

### Recurse with Grep While Ignoring Missing/Unreadable Files

The BSD and GNU grep utilities have options that can save you the hassle of using *find*, *xargs*, *et al.* in many cases. This is one of those. For example:

```
grep -Flrs "a1009206_vcr" . > file.log
```

This uses the following flags:

- `-F, --fixed-strings`

  > Interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings (i.e. force grep to
  > behave as fgrep).
- `-l, --files-with-matches`

  > Only the names of files containing selected lines are written to
  > standard output.  grep will only search a file until a match has
  > been found, making searches potentially less expensive.  Path-
  > names are listed once per file searched.  If the standard input
  > is searched, the string ``(standard input)'' is written.
- `-R, -r, --recursive`

  > Recursively search subdirectories listed.
- `-s, --no-messages`

  > Silent mode.  Nonexistent and unreadable files are ignored (i.e.
  > their error messages are suppressed).

to recurse down through the present working directory (e.g. `.` or `$PWD` if you prefer) and writing a list of filenames with matches to *file.log*. The `-s` flag keeps permissions errors or other cruft from cluttering your output file. You can also turn off standard error with `2>&-` if you're so inclined.

### Caveat: Symlinks and Recursion

The above *should* work in most cases, but you may also need to add either `-O` or `-p` if you're recursing and don't want to follow some or all of your symlinks. The man page has more specifics about grep's default behavior regarding symlinks, with and without recursing.